# How to use "HttpRequest", "FullHttpRequest", "HttpMessage", "FullHttpMessage" and "LastHttpContent"?

Tags: netty

I am trying to use `netty` to write some HTTP application. But I am confused by the so many similar types:

- HttpRequest
- FullHttpRequest
- HttpMessage
- FullHttpMessage
- HttpResponse
- FullHttpResponse
- LastHttpContent

I guess I lack an understanding of `netty's design philosophy` behind this.

Could anyone shed some light?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When an HTTP message is decoded by an `HttpObjectDecoder`, the decoder produces the following objects:

1. An `HttpRequest` or an `HttpResponse` that provides the properties decoded from the initial line and its following headers.
2. A series of `HttpContent`. The last `HttpContent` is `LastHttpContent`.

A typical handler code will look like the following:

```
if (msg instanceof HttpRequest) {
    ...
}
if (msg instanceof HttpContent) {
    ...
    if (msg instanceof LastHttpContent) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Please note that the `if` blocks are not mutually exclusive and thus the handler does not return when one of the 3 conditions above is met.  Take a look into [HttpSnoopServerHandler](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.1/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http/snoop/HttpSnoopServerHandler.java#L60) for a concrete example.

Now, let's take a look at `FullHttpRequest`. It implements `HttpRequest`, `HttpContent`, and `LastHttpContent`.  The well-written handler should just work when we inserted `HttpObjectAggregator` into the pipeline without changing any code.

So, the intention of this weird-looking class hierarchy is to enable a user to choose to use `HttpObjectAggregator` or not.

However, I do agree this is not intuitive. We are going to fix this in Netty 5 in such a way that the decoder produces only a single HTTP message object and streaming its content to it later.

Comment: No problem. Glad that it was helpful.

Comment: @trustin:  so you are saying that when we inserted HttpObjectAggregator into the pipeline, we get FullHttpRequest object with all the content of the payload? thanks..

Comment: I do not see changes about HTTP in http://netty.io/wiki/new-and-noteworthy-in-5.0.html Is it still under construction?

Comment: @trustin so `HttpObjectAggregator` always produces a `FullHttpRequest`?

Comment: @DmitryMinkovsky Yes.